# How can I know my google analytics shows the true conversion rate?

Tags: google-analytics

I am not sure about my analytic conversion rate because Adobe Analytics and Google Analytics shows different ratios.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

They will never match. But generally they are close to each other. The below article explains the possible reasons behind the difference in metrics.

http://www.searchdiscovery.com/blog/comparing-data-adobe-analytics-vs-google-analytics/

Also, it depends on how you define your conversions rates.